# Clicking a nested button in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML:

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6 individual " style="display: block;">
  <button style="position:relative; z-index:4; padding:8px 7px 8px 30px; font-size:16px; font-family: Calibri,Arial,Tahoma; color:black;" class="excel-button">Bajar Tabla</button>
  <!-- small box-->
  <div data-name="cardColor" class="small-box bg-purple">
    <div class="inner">
      <h4 data-name="title">Semana 9</h4>
      <p data-name="dateRange">26-febrero al 02-marzo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="icon"><i data-name="week" class="fa">9</i></div>
    <a class="small-box-footer" data-name="commentFooter">Sin enviar a revisión&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="text-warning fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="comment-box text-left" style="display: none;">
    <div data-name="comment" class="comment-inner text-danger" style="margin-right:15px">Este reporte no ha sido enviado a revisión</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The outer div is a clickable div, and I am trying to make the inner button clickable too. But when I click the button it triggers the actions of the div instead of the button's actions. How can I make it so when the user clicks the button it ignores the div element?

Comment: Call `stopPropagation()` on the event in the handler of the inner button. If you want an example of exactly how to do this, please add your JS code to the question

Answer (score 2):

This is called event bubbling. When an event occurs on an element, the handler will run on the initial element, then it will bubble up to parent elements that have the same event. Most events bubble up, with the exception of some, e.g. `focus`. So your initial button click handler will fire, and then your div click will fire.

To stop propogation, call `stopPropagation()` on the event object.

Bubbling is where events propagate upwards in the DOM tree, capturing is where events propogate down.

[See here for more information.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Try clicking on both `div` and `button`

```js
$(function(){
  $('div').click(function(event){
    alert('clicked on div');
  });
  
  $('button').click(function(event){
    event.stopImmediatePropagation(); //This ensures that div's onclick event is not fired
    alert('clicked on button');
  });
});
```

```css
div{
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f4f4f4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
```